# recursively copy file from subfolder to folder and rename it as folder and zip all subfolders

Tags: copy, directory, rename, subdirectory

I need help to create a script to copy the file asset-128@2x.png from round (i need to ignore the square subfolder because it also has a file asset-128@2x.png) subfolder in the main folder (robot, plane) and rename it to the main folder robot.png / plane.png and zip subfolders (round, square) to the same folder name robot.zip / plane.zip
I have mac and windows.

```
├── robot
│    ├── round
│    │       ├── asset-20@2x.png
│    │       ├── asset-30@2x.png
│    │       ├── asset-64@2x.png
│    │       └── asset-128@2x.png
│    └── square
│            ├── asset-20@2x.png
│            ├── asset-30@2x.png
│            ├── asset-64@2x.png
│            └── asset-128@2x.png
├── plane
│    ├── round
│    │       ├── asset-20@2x.png
│    │       ├── asset-30@2x.png
│    │       ├── asset-64@2x.png
│    │       └── asset-128@2x.png
│    └── square
│            ├── asset-20@2x.png
│            ├── asset-30@2x.png
│            ├── asset-64@2x.png
│            └── asset-128@2x.png
```

the result should be like this

```
├── robot
│    ├── round
│    │       ├── asset-20@2x.png
│    │       ├── asset-30@2x.png
│    │       ├── asset-64@2x.png
│    │       └── asset-128@2x.png
│    ├── square
│    │       ├── asset-20@2x.png
│    │       ├── asset-30@2x.png
│    │       ├── asset-64@2x.png
│    │       └── asset-128@2x.png
│    ├── robot.png
│    └── robot.zip
├── plane
│    ├── round
│    │       ├── asset-20@2x.png
│    │       ├── asset-30@2x.png
│    │       ├── asset-64@2x.png
│    │       └── asset-128@2x.png
│    ├── square
│    │       ├── asset-20@2x.png
│    │       ├── asset-30@2x.png
│    │       ├── asset-64@2x.png
│    │       └── asset-128@2x.png
│    ├── plane.png
│    └── plane.zip
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried several scripts that I tweaked but with no successful result and did not save them